# How to add the last value of an ID into the values of the next ID

Tags: r, bioinformatics

This question should be very simple, but I don't exactly know how to do it in R. Basically I have a two-column file, in which, the first column represents scaffold IDs and the second column is the position of an SNP in that particular scaffold.

```
id    POS
0001  38
0001  46
0001  50
0002  17
0002  23
0002  46
0003  13
0003  19
0003  38
...   ...
```

And I would like to create a new column in which, the SNP position (NEW_POS) for the first scaffold is the same, but for the second scaffold (and thereafter) the NEW_POS would be the result of adding the last POS value of the previous scaffold to each POS in the second scaffold (i.e. 50+17, 50+23, 50+46,...). For the third scaffold (96+13, 96+19, 96+38, ...) and so on. As you can see here:

```
id    POS  NEW_POS
0001  38   38
0001  46   46
0001  50   50
0002  17   67
0002  23   73
0002  46   96
0003  13   109
0003  19   115
0003  38   134
...   ...  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `lag` and `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
    mutate(
        scf.len = (id != lag(id, default = id[1])) * lag(POS, default = 0),
        New_POS = cumsum(scf.len) + POS
    )  %>%
    select(-scf.len)
#     id POS New_POS
# 1 0001  38      38
# 2 0001  46      46
# 3 0001  50      50
# 4 0002  17      67
# 5 0002  23      73
# 6 0002  46      96
# 7 0003  13     109
# 8 0003  19     115
# 9 0003  38     134
```

The data:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(id = c("0001", "0001", "0001", "0002", "0002", 
"0002", "0003", "0003", "0003"), POS = c(38, 46, 50, 17, 23, 
46, 13, 19, 38)), .Names = c("id", "POS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution which uses also `shift()` and `cumsum()` but *updates on join*

```
library(data.table)
DT[DT[, last(POS), id][, .(id, shift(cumsum(V1), fill = 0))], on = "id", 
   NEW_POS := POS + V2][]
```

which returns

```
     id POS NEW_POS
1: 0001  38      38
2: 0001  46      46
3: 0001  50      50
4: 0002  17      67
5: 0002  23      73
6: 0002  46      96
7: 0003  13     109
8: 0003  19     115
9: 0003  38     134
```

#### Explanation

```
tmp <- DT[, last(POS), id][, .(id, shift(cumsum(V1), fill = 0))][]
tmp
#     id V2
#1: 0001  0
#2: 0002 50
#3: 0003 96
```

picks the last value of each `id` group, shifts (lags) it by one, and computes the cumulative sum.

Then this result is right joined on `id` with the full data.table

```
DT[tmp, on = "id", NEW_POS := POS + V2][]
```

thereby creating `NEW_POS` *in place*.

#### Data

```
DT <- structure(list(id = c("0001", "0001", "0001", "0002", "0002", 
"0002", "0003", "0003", "0003"), POS = c(38L, 46L, 50L, 17L, 
23L, 46L, 13L, 19L, 38L)), .Names = c("id", "POS"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
#coerce to data.table
setDT(DT)
```